# How to smoother animation with animate()?

Tags: javascript, css, dart

I am using `animate()` and properties left, but if is motion slowly, then image moves pixel to pixel and not correspondence double type variable.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually more efficient to animate using the css transform translate, instead of setting left. See this [article](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/). Here's an [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) which explains why this is the case.

It looks like modern browsers support sub pixel translate values i.e '5.2px'. For browsers that don't you can also use translate scale to shrink your element down to 1/10 it's normal size, this will allow you to translate an element 1/10 of a pixel.

This question isn't specific to Dart, consider rewording it, and adding javascript and css tags as it will then be exposed to a wider audience.

Comment: thanks, work fine with this code:
`element.style.transform = "translate3d(${dx}px, ${dy}px, 0)";` But translate3d not work older browser:(

Comment: Try using translate() instead of translate3D() that has better browser support. http://caniuse.com/#search=translate  However IE8 is not supported, so if you need to target IE8, you'll have to browser sniff, and use absolute left positioning as a fallback.